# Make the user able to autopaste info in forms in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

After a few hours of googlening and testing I gave up the whole autofill a form in uiwebview and will now try another approch. However, I have no idea how to make it work.

All I really wanna do is to have two buttons, "username" and "password". The user will then highlight one of the forms textfields inside the webview and then press on of the buttons and the username will be printed in the textfield (if they pushed the username button that is).

So i want help with trying to understand how to control when they are highlighting a textfiled (ofc the keyboard will show up) and how i simulate a pastefunction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the content of an UIWebView injecting JavaScript, there are a [few topics around  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616599/programmatically-handling-a-text-field-within-a-uiwebview) about that (edit: [Also check this page](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview)).

In fact, you could automatically hand the the login/password directly through a javascript submit form action, instead of having to fill the visual form.

To get the contents of the Clipboard, use:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *pastedText = pasteboard.string;
```

(**Note:** The pasteboard is independent from your OS, meaning that if you copy something, it won't be recognized in the iphone app, you need to copy something from inside your iphone/simulator, the easiest way is to add a temporary UITextField, or go to the home screen, and get to the search page, and write there)

Comment: hi. thnk you for your qick reply, howvere i think u missunderstood me. I never ment to use the pastebin cus I have all the info in a database locally. But I manage to find my way with one of your links. When the person makes a field active and press the usernamebutton this function is called: NSString *jScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.activeElement;" 
          "field.value='%@';", self.username];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString];

Comment: Ok, the "How to simulate the paste function" really confused me, but again, the first part of my answer still holds up. Instead of replacing, just send the data through a submit in Javascript.